# dc.js charts with Angular2+

Tags: angular, dc.js, crossfilter

Has any one used dc.js with Angular2+ application. Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

I am able to make my application running on normal html/java-script. Now I need to implement the same in Angular 2+ application.

Comment: I don't know much Angular, but a few people I've talked to just leave their dc.js / d3 stuff in plain Javascript. (That's how I did it the one time I worked with Angular.) Frameworks like [angular-dc](https://github.com/TomNeyland/angular-dc) are impressive but that's for Angular 1 and it doesn't seem like a perfect mapping.

Comment: You can use library such as https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-service an typings such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dc to import d3/dc in your Angular project and replicate the features in typescript. It takes some times to learn the types but is feasible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**: A couple of weeks later I have a much better understanding and can maybe give some better instructions, so here It goes:

After generating the angular project, install *dc*, its typefiles, and all needed dependencies like this:

```
npm i --save dc @types/dc crossfilter2 d3 @types/d3
```

Note that *@types/crossfilter* is not needed since crossfilter started to supply their own typefile directly inside their package.
After that you can import *dc*, *crossfilter*, and *d3* by importing them in the component and use them like this:

**component.html**:

```
<div #nameOfDiv></div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as dc from 'dc';
import * as crossfilter from 'crossfilter2';
import {Dimension} from 'crossfilter2';

export class Graph {
    @ViewChild('nameOfDiv') chartDiv: ElementRef;
    private ndx: Dimension<T> = crossfilter<T>([{...}, {...}]);

    [...]

    paint() {
        let chart = dc.scatterPlot(this.chartDiv.nativeElement);
        chart.render();
    }
}
```

In the end do not forget to include the dcjs css stylesheet, either in the index.html as written in the old answer or wherever you'd like.

---

**Old answer**:
I'm currently at the same point, have some limited experience with dc.js, d3.js, and crossfilter2 in plain html and js. Now I want to use dcjs in Angular 5.

I just painted the first mock example in a component by installing the @types files for dc, d3, and crossfilter and including the actual libraries in the index.html header.

**index.html**

```
<head>
[...]
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter2/1.4.5/crossfilter.js" rel="script"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.9/dc.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.9/dc.css" />
</head>
```

**ng installs**

```
ng install --save @types/dc
ng install --save @types/d3
ng install --save @types/crossfilter
```

**component.ts**

```
import * as dc from 'dc';
import * as CrossFilter from 'crossfilter';

interface Data {
date: string;
quantity: number;
[...]
}

export class GraphComponent {
  private chart: dc.PieChart;
  private ndx: CrossFilter.CrossFilter<Data> = crossfilter<Data>([{ date: '2011-11-14T16:17:54Z', quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: 'tab' }, {...}])

  paintChart(): void {
    this.chart = dc.pieChart('#id__html_div');
    let dim = this.data.dimension((d) => d.date);
    let group = dim.group().reduceCount();
    this.chart.width(200).height(200).dimension(dim).group(group);
    dc.renderAll();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps a little. All of this is just what I did in the last few hours, this does not mean this is the intended way or the best way. I'm new to Angular and dcjs as well..