# crossfilter2__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to integrate dc.js Chart library in my angular project. I followed a link on SO which indicates how to integrate dc.js charts with angular2+ [dc.js charts with Angular2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104529/dc-js-charts-with-angular2) . I ran the following line to install all the packages needed.

`npm i --save dc @types/dc crossfilter2 d3 @types/d3`

I have a basic angular project. My Angular version is 7, I'm also attaching my `app.component.html` , `app.component.ts`, `app.module.ts` , `package.json` and my `angular.json` files below.

**app.component.html**

`<div #nameOfDiv></div>`

**app.component.ts**

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as dc from "dc";
import * as crossfilter from "crossfilter2";
import { Dimension } from "crossfilter2";

interface Data {
  letter: string;
  frequency: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("nameOfDiv", { static: false }) chartDiv: ElementRef;

  title = "DC";

  private chart: dc.PieChart;
  private ndx: any = crossfilter<Data>([
    { letter: "B", frequency: 2 },
    { letter: "A", frequency: 10 }
  ]);

  paintChart(): void {
    this.chart = dc.pieChart("#pie");
    let dim = this.ndx.dimension((d: any) => d.letter);
    let group = dim.group().reduceCount();
    this.chart
      .width(200)
      .height(200)
      .dimension(dim)
      .group(group);
    dc.renderAll();
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "DC": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/DC",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "DC:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "DC:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "DC:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "DC:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "DC:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "DC"
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.2",
    "@types/dc": "0.0.29",
    "crossfilter2": "^1.5.2",
    "d3": "^5.15.0",
    "dc": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.21",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.21",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

When I compile and run this project I see the following error.

[image: Error : crossfilter2__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not a function]

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Please see [this issue](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/147). I believe (although I haven't tried it myself) that you need to do `import crossfilter from 'crossfilter2';` This appears to be close to the final example in the Q&A you linked, although there is obviously a lot of confusion in this area.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue and the following approach worked for me.

```
import * as crossfilter from 'crossfilter2/crossfilter';
crossFilterObj = crossfilter(data);
```

Comment: Can you share what Angular version you were using?

Comment: Funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working in Angular 11 and `"crossfilter2": "^1.5.4"` like this:

**component.ts**

```js
import crossfilter from 'crossfilter2';

// ...
crossFilterObj = crossfilter(data)
```

I also had to add the following field to my `tsconfig.json` to silence an error.

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Your solution works also for Angular 12.2